# How can I make a button redirect my page to another page using a controller action and passing a value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

So here is my page(PlayGame). Generated from my controller action as:

```
   // GET: Games/PlayGame/Id
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult PlayGame(Game game)
   {
       return View(game);
   }
```

On the PlayGame page I would like to do a action defined in my javascript. Here is the the .cshtml page for PlayGame:

```
   @model CapstoneApplication.Models.Game

   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/RouletteWheel.js")

   <input type="button" value="Spin" style="float:left" id="spin"/>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   <input type="submit" value="Play" style="float:left" id="play" 
   onclick="play(@Model.Id)" />

   <script src="~/Scripts/RouletteWheel.js"></script>
```

This action is supposed to reference a javascript file action:

```
   function play(gameId) {
      window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")';
   }
```

When this action is invoked I want to navigate to the PlayGameRound page and pass a gameId and category from the .js file.

```
   //POST:    Games/PlayGameRound/GameId/Category
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult PlayGameRound(int gameId, string category)
   {
      //TODO: Get the selected category and shoot a random question from 
      the category
      var random = new Random();
      var game = this.db.Games.Find(gameId);
      var questionIndex = random.Next(0, game.Round.Questions.Count);
      var question = game.Round.Questions.ElementAt(questionIndex);

      if (category.Equals("Crown"))
      {

      }

      while (question.Category.CategoryName != category)
      {
         questionIndex = random.Next(0, game.Round.Questions.Count);
         question = game.Round.Questions.ElementAt(questionIndex);
      }

      return View(game);
  }
```

For some reason when this function in the .js gets called:

```
  function play(gameId) {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")';
  }
```

It returns me this page:

[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTHrX.png)

and the Url returned is /Games/PlayGame/@Url.Action(%22PlayGameRound%22,%20%22Games%22) but

I am trying to request something like: /Games/PlayGameRound/GameId/Category

Please Help.

Comment: You can't use Razor syntax in a javascript file, Razor syntax is only usable in the View, .cshtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Url.Action` method is a c# method call and you cannot use c# in a seperate js file, but you can if it is in the razor view.

What you can do is add another parameter that can take the url as well and use it to redirect like:

```
onclick="play(@Model.Id,'@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")')"
```

and then in your function use it:

```
function play(gameId,url) {
window.location.href = url;
}
```

or another alternative is to use `data-` attribute like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Play" style="float:left" id="play" 
 data-id="@Model.Id"
 data-url="@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")" onclick="play(this)" />
```

and in the function in js:

```
function play(element) {
var ModelID = $(element).data("id"); // ModelId
window.location.href = $(element).data("url"); // url
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

As I stated, you can't use Razor syntax in the javascript file, it can only be used in the View files, so change your javascript line of code from this:

```
    function play(gameId) {
       window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")';
  }
```

To this:

```
    function play(gameId) {
          window.location.href = '/Games/PlayGameRound';

  }
```

Comment: Thank you this fixes the crash but doesn't pass the value from my game object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put razor syntax inside a js file. Another way around this is to create global object in the view and reference the same object inside your js file.
      @model CapstoneApplication.Models.Game

```
   <script>
       var globalObj = {
          myRoute: '@Url.Action("PlayGameRound", "Games")';
       }
   </script>

   <input type="button" value="Spin" style="float:left" id="spin"/>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   <input type="submit" value="Play" style="float:left" id="play" 
   onclick="play(@Model.Id)" />

   <script src="~/Scripts/RouletteWheel.js"></script>
```

And inside your js file

```
 function play(gameId) {
    window.location.href = window.myRoute;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this fixes the crash, but doesn't pass the value from my game object.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use Razor syntax in JavaScript file as it was said. You have to add the url as a parameter of your JavaScript function so you can use the Razor syntax to get it in your HTML.

AND

You put `[HttpPost]` on your controller method and you want to get it in « Get », it’s not possible.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.